# Create promise for api in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, authentication

I am building authentication for web app and I am stuck when I send login data to server but I can't do it asynchronous because my function I have created do not returns promise.

So What I want to accomplish is when I fill up the form I press the button and that's executes function onSubmit(), which validates entered data, then if everything is OK executes passed function submit(). Then function submit() executes api.user.login(data) function where data is sent to server and receives information about user registration status. If login status is success user will be redirected to user page, but I am stuck when api.user.login() is called it don't return promise.

I get error like you can see bellow when I submit form data. However server still receives form data.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
LoginPage._this.submit
src/components/pages/LoginPage.js:17
  14 | }
  15 | 
  16 | submit = data => {
> 17 |   api.user.login(data)
  18 |   .then(res => {
  19 |     if (res.data === "loginSucces") {
  20 |       <Redirect to="/user"/>
View compiled
LoginForm._this.onSubmit
src/components/pages/forms/LoginForm.js:26
  23 | 
  24 | //is empty method or ES6 Object.keys(errs) takes all the keys
  25 | if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
> 26 |   this.props.submit(this.state.data)
  27 |   // console.log("hello");
  28 |   // this.props.submit()
  29 | }
```

What I tried to do is to wrap login function in new Promise(), but that definitely didn't work.

```
    return new Promise((resolve, rejec) => {
           let data = JSON.stringify(credentials);
           axios.post("/register", data
           ).then(function(res) {
               console.log(res);
               return res.data
           }).catch(function(error) {
               console.log(error);
            });

})
```

So My code for Login page is bellow:

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './forms/LoginForm';
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import api from "../../api.js"
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'

class LoginPage  extends React.Component
{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    submit = data => {
      api.user.login(data).then(res => {
        if (res === "loginSucces") {
          <Redirect to="/user"/>
        }
      }).cache(err=>{
        console.error(err);
      })
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <h1>Login page</h1>
              <LoginForm submit={this.submit}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Login form code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormFeedback} from 'reactstrap';

class LoginForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data:{},
            loading: false,
            errors: {}
        };
    }

    onChange = e =>
        this.setState({
            data: {...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}})

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
        this.setState({ errors: errors })

        //is empty method or ES6 Object.keys(errs) takes all the keys
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
          this.props.submit(this.state.data)
          // console.log("hello");
          // this.props.submit()
        }
    }

    validate = (data) => {
        const errors = {};

        //TODO cant be special sibols, to short etc
        if(!data.username) {
            errors.username = "Can't be bank";
        }
        if(!data.password){
            errors.password = "Can't be bank";
        }

        return errors;
    }

    render() {

        return(

            //TODO form still reloads

            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="username">Username</Label>
                    <Input
                            invalid={!!this.state.errors.username}
                            name="username"
                           id="username"
                           placeholder="What is your username?"
                           value = {this.state.data.username}
                           onChange = {this.onChange}
                    />
                    <FormFeedback invalid >{this.state.errors.username}</FormFeedback>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                    <Input invalid={!!this.state.errors.password}
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        id="password"
                        placeholder="Make it secure"
                        value = {this.state.data.password}
                        onChange = {this.onChange}
                    />
                    <FormFeedback invalid >{this.state.errors.password}</FormFeedback>
                </FormGroup>
                <Button preventDefault>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        )
    }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default LoginForm;
```

API code:

```
import axios from "axios"

export default {
    user: {
        login: credentials =>{
                let data = JSON.stringify(credentials);
                axios.post("/register", data
                ).then(function(res) {
                  console.log(res);
                  return res.data
                }).catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });
              },
          test: () => {console.log("test in api")}
    }
}
```

This is console.log(res) output:

```
{
  data: "loginSucces",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  headers: {
    …
  },
  config: {
    …
  },
  …
}config: adapter: ƒxhrAdapter(config)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "xhrAdapter"prototype: {
  constructor: ƒ
}__proto__: ƒ()[
  [
    FunctionLocation
  ]
]: xhr.js: 11[
  [
    Scopes
  ]
]: Scopes[
  2
]data: "{"username":"sdfsdfdfsdfsdfsdgsdfgsdgsadgsdgsdag","password":"sdfsdfsdfsdf345235235"}"headers: Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"__proto__: ObjectmaxContentLength: -1method: "post"timeout: 0transformRequest: {
  0: ƒ
}transformResponse: {
  0: ƒ
}url: "/register"validateStatus: ƒvalidateStatus(status)xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"__proto__: Objectdata: "loginSucces"headers: connection: "close"content-length: "11"content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"date: "Fri, 30 Mar 2018 20:03:56 GMT"etag: "W/"b-JeyKc7pdZbjTvd8ActAidnhWojA""vary: "Accept-Encoding"x-powered-by: "Express"__proto__: Objectrequest: XMLHttpRequestonabort: nullonerror: ƒhandleError()onload: nullonloadend: nullonloadstart: nullonprogress: nullonreadystatechange: ƒhandleLoad()ontimeout: ƒhandleTimeout()readyState: 4response: "loginSucces"responseText: "loginSucces"responseType: ""responseURL: "http://localhost:3000/register"responseXML: nullstatus: 200statusText: "OK"timeout: 0upload: XMLHttpRequestUploadonabort: nullonerror: nullonload: nullonloadend: nullonloadstart: nullonprogress: nullontimeout: null__proto__: XMLHttpRequestUploadwithCredentials: false__proto__: XMLHttpRequeststatus: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: constructor: ƒObject()hasOwnProperty: ƒhasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒisPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒpropertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒtoLocaleString()toString: ƒtoString()valueOf: ƒvalueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ__defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ__defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ__lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ__lookupSetter__()get__proto__: ƒ__proto__()set__proto__: ƒ__proto__()
```

Comment: What response you receive that `console.log(res)` ?

Comment: Just checked, request to server works fine, I can send form data to server and server sends back acknowledgement.

Comment: Please see in edited question.

Comment: Change this line `if (res === "loginSucces")` to `if (res.data === "loginSucces")`

Comment: Yes this is a mistake, but it not affects this problem, becouse I cant use .then() if there is no promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There's something you need to know

`axios` is a Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

- Make XMLHttpRequests from the browser
- Make http requests from node.js
- Supports the Promise API
- Intercept request and response

  > - Transform request and response data
- Cancel requests
- Automatic transforms for JSON data
- Client side support for protecting against XSRF

Axios don't will return a Promise.

#### Oficial implementation about `post`

> Performing a POST request

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Your implementation it was coded as below:

```
login: credentials =>{
    let data = JSON.stringify(credentials);
    axios.post("/register", data
    ).then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      return res.data
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
```

Seems like that the output is a content of `data` attribute.

References:

https://github.com/axios/axios